# OpenCL: Sending same cl_mem to multiple devices

Tags: opencl

I am writing a multi-GPU parallel algorithm. One of the issues I am facing is to find out what would happen if I push one cl_mem to multiple devices, and let them run the same kernel at the same time. The kernel will make change to the memory passed to device.

It is very time consuming to code and debug OpenCL code. So before I start doing it I want to take some advices from fellow Stackoverflow users - I want to know the consequence of doing such thing, in both of below scenarios (e.g will there be any exception raised during execution? Are data synchronized? When CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR is used is the same region of memory pointed by this cl_mem get properly copied to device? etc.):

1. The memory is created with CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR
2. The memory is created with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Appendix A of the OpenCL Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) explains the required synchronization for objects shared between different command queues.

Basically it says you should use OpenCL events and `clFlush` to synchronize execution between the command queues.  The OpenCL implementation will synchronize the contents of the memory objects between the different devices of the OpenCL context. USE/COPY _HOST_PTR does not make any difference, but USE_HOST_PTR will avoid a couple of extra copies of the data in host memory. Use `clEnqueueMapBuffer` to synchronize bits with the host at the end.

Comment: It says "The results of modifying a shared resource in one command-queue while it is being used by another command-queue are undefined.". This is actually what I am doing - changing one cl_mem on multiple GPUs. As a consequence I get random bluescreens after the program started running for a minute or so... Very strange.

Comment: What about situation, when multiple command queues, on multiple devices write to the same memory buffer but on different areas of this buffer?

Comment: It's undefined. If I remember correctly, it's mentioned in the same Appendix.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything explicit in the OpenCL specifications that guarantees that data will be synchronised across devices.  I don't see how the OpenCL implementation would know how to distribute a buffer across multiple devices and how to aggregate those buffers again later.

The approach I've adopted is to create a separate context, read, write and kernel exec queues for each device.  I then create separate buffers on each device and enqueue writes/reads to move data to/from the devices.  Hence I explicitly handle all of that myself.

I'd like a better solution, but at least the above method works and doesn't rely on anything that is implementation specific.